# JQueryMobile Background Image Resizing

Tags: image, css, jquery-mobile, background

I'm doing a Phonegap App with JQueryMobile.

The different pages have different Background Images (defined by jquery code) and I'm seeing a disturbing behavior when the user enter the page ONLY THE FIRST TIME.

The problem is it occurs a resizing of the image in the first second. That is, when the user enter the page it shows a resolution, and a second after, the image resize again. And after that I can exit and enter again that page and DOES NOT RESIZE.

The HTML that define the page:

```
<div id="pageHoja1" class="divPagina" data-role="page">
</div>

<div id="pageHoja2" class="divPagina" data-role="page">
</div>

<div id="pageHoja3" class="divPagina" data-role="page">
</div>
```

The CSS of that page changes dynamically:

In the on-device-ready:

```
$(".divPagina").css("background-size","cover");
```

On the function that decides the background image:

```
$("#pageHoja" + i).css("background-image", "url('mycharts/" + sFileBackg + "')");
```

Ideally I would like to NOT RESIZE AT ALL (because I want the original size). But if that is impossible, at least I want the resize to occur before it shows to the user.

I've already tried this but with same results... ;(

```
$.mobile.loadPage("#pageHoja" + i);
$("#pageHoja" + i).page(true);
```

and I've checked the CSS of background-size BEFORE and AFTER (with an alert message) and both gives "cover" value...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When does the `$("#pageHoja" + i)` code is executed?

Comment: @ojovirtual it execute on a function triggered by a button in another page. It's like you are in the Welcome Page and select (by a Button) which will be the background image in the Next Page...